# Pinterest like select box for boards

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, combobox, twitter-bootstrap-3, pinterest

Pinterst has a very nice and useful select box (combobox or dropdown) for boards.

It allows to select an existing board or create new board on the fly and selects the newly created board.

I want to implement something similar to this on my new project.
Are there any jQuery plugins similar to this functionality. Any related tutorial or resource is also welcome.
I'm using Bootstrap 3.1.1 with jQuery 1.11.0.

Screen shot of pinterest select box is attached.

[image]

Comment: find tutorials in Google. Show your codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like Select2 (https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2), and customize it using jQuery to get similiar functionality..

http://www.bootply.com/122726

Answer (score 0):

I found this Plugin called "Chosen".
Very robust plugin with my required functionality.

https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166

I haven't tested this but looks promising.

EDIT:
I used the Chosen plugin.

The original plugin does not support adding new items and saving them in DB on the fly.

This pull request adds the functionality. https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166

Worked seamlessly for me.

Read the comments for this pull request for more info.